# Background image doesn't show within the <div> element - CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

[image: screenshot of the directory structure]
I created a `<div>` element and I'm going to use below `css` style withing the `<div>` element.

```
#girls {
    background-image: url("girl.gif");
}
```

Here is my HTML `<div>` element (This element contains in `index.html` page):

```
        <div id="girls">
            <p>
            <b>Girls chat:</b> at the lounge, we're committed to providing you, our guest, with an exceptional
            experience every time you visit. Whether you're just stopping by to check in on email over an elixir, 
            or are here for an out-of-the-ordinary dinner, you'll find our knowledgeable service staff pay attention to every
            detail. If you're not fully satisfied, have a Blueberry Bliss Elixir on us.
        </p>
        </div>
```

But when I load index page, the background image (girl.gif) doesn't show up. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: The URLs in the stylesheet are relative to the CSS file's location, not HTML file's location.

Comment: move Girl.gif to stylesheet folder

Comment: `#girls {
    background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
}`

Comment: go one above and see, `../` your url might not be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#girls {
    background-image: url("../girl.gif");
}
```

I'm guessing that the `css` is inside that `stylesheet` folder, that's why you need to go up a level to access `girl.gif`, thus the usage of `../`

Comment: Hi, Sweller it worked. Can you tell me why we shoul put ../ followed by girl.gif?

Comment: `../` is used to go up one level in a directory

Comment: `../../` two directories up

Comment: `../../../` three directories up

Comment: `../../../../` four directories up

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GIF DEMO</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
#girls {
    background-image: url('demo.gif');
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div id="girls">Sample Text
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are using external CSS then Change your directory path of the image & try again.
else Inline Stlying go with the sample code 
image link
https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/25/81/28/258128ed71595efc9b561ed7d88b89f2.gif